# Using git svn inside a GitLab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, git-svn

I am facing the following situation: A SVN repository should be available in GitLab and a CI/CD pipeline should be created in GitLab CI/CD for it.

The difficulty is to synchronize SVN and Git. The requirement is that the tools used are free. Therefore I have to use "git svn" for this and tools like SubGit are out. Ideally the synchronization takes place within the pipeline. Furthermore the last SVN changes should be recognized in the pipeline. ("change" trigger)

Therefore my idea was the following:

initial: Clone via git svn the SVN repository. This will automatically create a master branch that tracks the svn repository. Then create an empty GitLab project and add it to the git svn repository as remote. Then use it to push the changes to GitLab.

In the pipeline: before the automatic git checkout (pre-clone step) clone the git repository, use "git svn rebase" to get the current SVN changes and then push the new state of the repository back to GitLab. (the .gitlab-ci.yml checked into SVN). Afterwards, the automatic checkout takes place and the rebased changes can be recognized in the "change" trigger.

The initial step works so far. The problem is that the .git folder is not pushed of course. Now when I use "git svn" commands inside the pipeline, it doesn't find the git svn remote. I already tried to trick around by manually copying the .git/config and the .git/svn/ folder of the initial step into the workingcopy of the GitLab runner as a pipeline step. But that just messes up the whole repository.

I explained the problem in such detail because otherwise this might be an XY problem. Do any of you have any ideas on how to approach this?